# How many hyper-rectangle-like objects are intersecting a hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics

Let $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n},\ b\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $\forall x\in \{-1,1\}^n : Ax\ne b$.

Let us denote: $S=\{x\in\mathbb R^n|Ax=b\}$ ('S' for solution set).

Is $\ \#\Big\{H\in\big\{ \{-1\}, \{1\}, (-1,1)\big\}^n \ \Big|\ H\cap S\ne\emptyset\ \Big\} = O(n)$?

where '#' denotes the cardinality of the set.

My intuition tells me that this should be true, but I can't figure out how to prove or disprove it.

So far, I've done many trial and error "experiments" that also support my conjecture, but I am stuck in proving/ disproving it in the general case.

By the way, it is easy to see that WLOG the solution set is a hyper-plane. So, we can modify $S$ to be $S=\{x\in\mathbb R^n|a^T x=b\}$ for $a\in\mathbb R^n, b\in\mathbb R$ such that $\forall x\in \{0,1\}^n:a^T x\ne b$.

Comment: I think you mean certain equivalence classes of points.  Are you asking how many faces intersect a solution set? By the way, if b is zero and A is zero, the answer is probably "No", so you should expect an answer conditional on the real rank of A.  Gerhard "Unsure Which Grouping Is Used" Paseman, 2018.09.19.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I edited my question and added some more essential requirement: that $\forall x\in \{0,1\}^n : Ax\ne b$.

Comment: @DudiFrid: I believe that you may drop the corners $\{-1\}^n$ and $\{1\}^n$, because they are always just two points, and this does not change the asymptotics.

Comment: @AlexM. My bad, it was just a typo. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @DudiFrid: Notice that I have made a change in the definition of the set that you are describing, please check whether it conveys what you meant to say.

Comment: @AlexM. I initialy thought you just added the slashes in the missing places, but now I see that the rest of your edition is different than I meant, so I restored my version

Comment: If you're going to use asymptotic notation like $O(n)$, don't you need an infinite family of matrices $A_n$ and vectors $b_n$?  What properties should these objects share?

Comment: Only that $\forall x\in \{0,1\}^nAx\ne b$ as I wrote

Comment: @DudiFrid: My objection is related to the fact that the notation $\big\{ \{-1\}, \{1\}, (-1,1)\big\}^n$ is *definitely* not what you mean: for instance, if $n=4$, one element of this set is $\big\{ \{1\}, \{-1\},(0,1), (0,1) \big\}$ (its components are subsets of the interval $[-1,1]$, not numbers). Why don't you say in English words what you want?

Comment: @AlexM. I want sets of points in $\mathbb R^n$, so for $n=4$ we get a set that contains elements such as $\{(-1,1,1,-1)\}, \{(-1,x,1,y)|x,y\in (0,1)\}$ and so on. How would you express that formally?

Comment: @DudiFrid: What you want is exactly the $n$-dimensional cube $[-1,1]^n$, which means $\{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb R^n \mid x_i \in [-1,1] \ \forall i = 1, \dots, n\}$.

Comment: @AlexM. I want **particular subsets** of the cube, not all the cube

Comment: @AlexM. BTW by "power of n" I mean cartesian product

Comment: @DudiFrid: You want these special points in the cube to have two coordinates equal to $\pm 1$? You see, your question is impossible to understand, and unless you manage to clarify it, it will be put on hold. In particular, it is not clear at all why your own answer is relevant to the question. Instead of using a mathematical notation, why don't you use plain English to express what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83510/discussion-between-dudi-frid-and-alex-m).

Answer (score 0):

Just take $\sum x_i=n-1$ and you get $O(n\cdot2^n)$ instead of $O(n)$.